# Can i do a fresh install ontop of outdated Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, system-installation

I have an outdated version of Ubuntu. Can I back up my files, download the latest version to a disk & do a complete fresh install of the latest version? Or do I need to uninstall the outdated version first? Sorry I am a beginner in Linux & trying to learn :)

Comment: @Tim Do I just open a terminal window & input that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing directly over the old version is the most stable and easiest way to upgrade. You could use a backup program like Aptik to back up your added repos and program configuration files, then use the file manager to backup your personal files to an external drive or use a cloud storage program like Dropbox.

Just choose to install over your old Ubuntu when installing with the Live CD, and it'll overwrite over the old version. This is also works if you need to overwrite another Ubuntu based distro such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of mine...

Comment: @Tim - a few extra details, like [where to get the installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/), how to back stuff up (and Formatting) could of done it

Answer (score 1):

Installing over the top is fine, just chose `Erase this disk and install` or `Install over Ubuntu XX.xx`. Make sure you have a backup and a list of programs.

<strike>However, you could upgrade it, preserving your documents etc, by running the command `sudo update-manager -d`</strike> - Wouldn't work for version 10.04.

Comment: I think you can only upgrade from the previously release (e.g. from 13.10 to 14.04).

Comment: @Wilf I went from 12.04 to 14.04

Comment: What version are you running at the moment?

Comment: I did an 13.10 to 14.04 with `apt-get` (dist-upgrade ? - don't remember) and had problems ONLY due to use of proprietary nvidia drivers.

Comment: Try disabling them first I guess, then re-enable after the upgrade?

Comment: @Tim The OP can not perform an automatic upgrade from an outdated version.

Comment: @dan08 They still haven't said what version it is, "outdated" may not actually mean outdated as we see it, it could be that they mean not the latest one?

Comment: Yes I think mine is 10.04 and wouldn't upgrade when I tried it previously.

Comment: @Tim fair enough. I assumed it was an EOL version but that wasn't apparent in the question.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to go via 12.04, which would take a long time. Fresh install is best.

Comment: @Wilf Just discovered, `sudo update-manager -d` will let me go up to 14.10, from 14.04. I'm guessing it still wouldn't work here though.

Comment: @Tim - considering 14.04 has only fairly recently been released, I wouldn't recommend it :D. The upgrader does mostly work, but due to software being different software versions and stuff, it is not as good as clean install because it can occasionally muck things up.

Comment: If I don't go with 14.04 then where do I find an older release to download?

Comment: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/